# MySQL Cluster Engine not supported

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding the MySQL Cluster. I installed via

"apt-get install mysql-server-cluster" the cluster on 3 Ubuntu 10.04 machines. Everything works fine. They are connected, one is the management node and the other two servers act as stroage nodes. Now I have a big problem. The ndbcluster engine is displayed as an engine within the engine list, but it is not supporoted. How can I enable the ndbcluster engine?

Thanks so much in advance.

BR,
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

The first recommendation I'd make is to use the latest version of MySQL Cluster 7.2 from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/

The other thing is to check that in the my.cnf file that you use for your mysqld process that you include the line...

ndbcluster

... under the "[mysqld]" tag.

You can tell if the mysqld process has then connected to the cluster by running "ndb_mgm -e show". If things still aren't going well then try following the instructions from this [blog on running MySQL Cluster over multiple Linux hosts](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/deploying-mysql-cluster-over-multiple-hosts/).

Regards, Andrew.